# truffle unbox react have Type error default.then is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, truffle, web3-react

Recently, I used truffle unbox example: (https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box)

But, I have facing big problem.
When I run my App.js with `npm run start`, It hasn't compile error.
However, when I connect my application on web browser,  It appear error, like this:
[image]

I also upgraded my nodejs and npm version, but all my attempting is fail.

My nodejs version is 7.10.1 and npm version is 6.4.1.

Why does this error occur? and what is the solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe post some code? web3 behaves in a weird fashion, and is async, so if you try to use it before it's ready, it'll error out in weird ways. Truffle does something like `const web3 = await getWeb3();` Also, don't use `componentWillMount` since it's considered legacy, try `componentDidMount` instead: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: Thanks, Predrag. As you said, I try to use componentDidMount function, but It still doesn't work. I'll keep going until solve this problem.

Comment: I finally solve my problem. My source code is written some bugs, and you give me some hint to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: no problem! Maybe answer your question with the solution, so others can find it too?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was calling `getWeb3` as a function, then chaining the `then`.
so instead of `getWeb3.then`, it's `getWeb3().then`.